# Create a class instance with a variable as parameter rather than a constant value

Tags: c++, templates

Here is an example:

```
template <int x>
class students
{
    int count = x;
};
students<10> first_class;
```

Above code gives creates first_class with count set to a value 10. Instead, can I create an instance with a variable rather than a value as in

```
template <int x>
class students
{
    int count = x;
};

students<var> first_class;
var = 10;
```

Here `var` is set to 10 after creating an instance. I wonder is there a way to achieve this? I'm not sure if this would be possible if I don't know the value of `x` at the time of creating the instance.

Comment: If you don't know `x` when you are compiling the program, templates are not possible I'm afraid.

Comment: you can do `first_class.count = 10` but you cannot use `var` as template parameter when it is not a constant

Comment: "I'm not sure if this would be possible if I don't know the value of x at the time of creating the instance." No, of course not. The entire point of templates is to do the work at compile time. If you do know the value (for example, because `var` is initialized with a constant and can't change before the instantiation of the template), see `constexpr`. If you want to set a member of the instance at the time the instance is created, based on information that's only determined at runtime, that's what a *constructor* is for.

Comment: what is the actual aim of this? `x` is used to initialze the member. After creating the instance you can assign any value you want

Comment: You seem to be skirting the purpose of a run-time *constructor*.

Comment: why is this a template anyway

Comment: Yeah, I understand it's not possible to create without the value of ```var```. The main aim of this question is how to tackle it if I don't know the value of ```var```. Avoid using templates?

Comment: It's a bit stronger than avoid. If you can't know the template parameters when compiling you can't use a template.

Comment: "The main aim of this question is how to tackle it if I don't know the value of var. Avoid using templates?"  Sorry but that doesnt make it more clear. If you dont know the value you want to use to initialize the member then  don't create the object. Wait until you know the value. And don't use the template parameter but just pass a parameter to the constructor

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have a better idea now.